# Card game - compare cards and play five rounds between two players

Tags: python-3.x, playing-cards

I'm trying to create a 5-round card game between two players (Human and Computer) using the Spanish-suited cards. While I can now deal the cards to two players and compare most of them, I have two main problems:

- I can't compare the dims that are not numbers ("Jack", "Knight", "King", "Ace"). My teacher suggested me to create a dictionary like this: dims = {2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five", 6: "six", 7: "seven", 8: "Jack", 9: "Knight", 10: "King", 11: "Ace"}. But I don't know how to use the numbers for comparison and then print (just print) the values in words. Any ideas?
- The other thing is that I don't know where exactly to write the loop to play the five rounds. The exercise also asks to press a key to play the next round, what function could I use in this case?

This is my code:

```
dims = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "Jack", "Knight", "King", "Ace"]
suits = ["golds", "cups", "swords", "clubs"]
deck = []

for d in dims:
    for s in suits:
        card = "{} of {}".format(d,s)
        deck.append(card)
        
random.shuffle(deck)

Human = [[]]
Computer = [[]]

for i in range(1):
    for j in range(1):
        Human[j].append(deck.pop(0))
        
for i in range(1):
    print("Human")
    for j in range (1):
        print("{:16}".format(Human[i][j]), end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(1):
    for j in range(1):
        Computer[j].append(deck.pop(0))
        
for i in range(1):
    print("Computer")
    for j in range (1):
        print("{:16}".format(Computer[i][j]), end=" ")
    print()
    
if Human>Computer:
    print("Human wins")
elif Computer>Human:
    print("Computer wins")
else:
    print("Draw")
```

Comment: I suggest only using numbers, then using a function to get the string representation of the card wherever you actually need to print it. Then you don't need to waste memory on a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you might want to check about [Python Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). You can store the numbers as keys, and the card values as values.

For your second question, I have read your code once and I couldn't understand why there are quite a lot of for loops with `range(1)`. If you want to run the methods once only, you don't need the loops.
Hint for running the game five times: from which line the game starts? at which line the game ends?